# Limit Comparison Test: Is there any intuition behind it?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The Limit Comparison Test:

> Let $ a_n > 0 $ and $ b_n > 0 $ for all $ n \geq N $, $ N $ an integer.
>
> **a)** If $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n/b_n = c > 0 $, then $ \sum_{n = 
> 1}^{\infty} a_n $ and $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n $ both converge or
>   both diverge.
>
> **b)** If $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n/b_n = 0 $ and $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n $ converges, then $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n $
>   converges.
>
> **c)** If $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n/b_n = \infty $ and $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} b_n $ diverges, then $ \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} a_n $
>   diverges.

I'm reviewing topics on infinite series and to me a lot of this area makes intuitive sense. One of the things that don't make intuitive sense to me, however, is the limit comparison test. So the question is: What is the intuition behind this test? Or is there any intuition behind it at all?

I'm not trying to understand the analytical proof/justification for the test - I already do. I just find it unenlightening.

Comment: Which one of $a), b)$ or $c)$ isn't intuitive?

Comment: Perhaps you can think about the case when $a_n/b_n=c$ (not just in the limit).

Comment: First of all, imagine $a_{n}$ exactly equals a constant times $b_{n}$, e.g. suppose $a_{n} = 4b_{n}$ for all $n$. Would you find it intuitive then the sum of $a_{n}$ and the sum of $b_{n}$ have the same convergence status (because one is just a constant multiple of the other)? If so, then I suppose that an intuition (for the case of $c > 0$) would be that if $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n} = c$, then for all large $n$, $a_{n}$ is "basically" just a constant $c$ times $b_{n}$, so the two sums should have the same convergence status.

Comment: A series of positive terms converges if the terms don't grow too fast. The limit comparison test is comparing the rates of growth of the terms from each series.

Comment: @Mattos None of these make intuitive sense to me. I know they are true but I don't look at any of them and feel like I understand them.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth that helped me, thank you.

Comment: @EthanBolker That helped too, thank you, although I'm still not feeling like I got this